# Cannot calculate with Dynamic variables in a grid

Tags: dynamic

This is a prototype of a grading scheme. In reality it is bigger. The  10 pts  in `initPtsPartA` comes from the school.

The output cell should be deployed as a CDF file for the teacher. The teacher enters the points of the students and get a final mark.

I have two questions.

1) How can I limit the `InputField` to allow for integer numbers between 0 and 10?  If I enter anything else, say a negative number or a symbol,  it should be cleared automatically.

2) In the Code Snippet section "Why don't the calculations work?" you see expressions with `Dynamic` variables which I need to work with. What is wrong? What is the solution?

```
DynamicModule[{
  mark4 = 1/3, mark3 = 0.51, mark2 = 0.68, mark1 = 0.80,
  initPtsPartA = {{10, 8, 10, 6}, {10, 5, 10, 5}, {10, 7, 10, 1}},
  initPtsStudent, initPtsSchool, initPtsPartSum, numTable, 
  SchoolAPts, StudentAPts, StudentMinAchieved
  }, 

 numTable[x_, y_ /; OddQ[y]] := initPtsPartA[[x, y]];
 numTable[x_, y_ /; EvenQ[y]] := InputField[Dynamic@initPtsPartA[[x, y]],
   Number, ContinuousAction -> True, FieldSize -> 1];

 initPtsPartSum[x_, y_, col_] := Dynamic@Total[initPtsPartA[[x ;; y, col]]];

 SchoolAPts = (Total[initPtsPartA[[1 ;; 3, #]]] &) /@ {1, 3};
 StudentAPts = (initPtsPartSum[1, 3, #] &) /@ {2, 4};

(* CODE SNIPPET, part of a longer program with `Graphics` involved. *)

Column[{Grid[
    Append[ Array[numTable, {3, 4}], (initPtsPartSum[1, 3, #] &) /@ 
      Range[4]]],

   {"Just Testing Values:", initPtsPartSum[1, 3, 1], 
    initPtsPartSum[1, 3, 2], initPtsPartSum[1, 3, 3], 
    initPtsPartSum[1, 3, 4], "Student Pts only:", StudentAPts},

   {"Why don't the calculations work?", 
    Dynamic[5*initPtsPartSum[1, 3, 2] + 10],   
    Dynamic[initPtsPartSum[1, 3, 4] > 30], 
    Dynamic[ Total[(initPtsPartSum[1, 3, #] &) /@ Range[4]]  ], 
    Dynamic[(Total@StudentAPts)]/(Total@SchoolAPts)},

   {"Why don't the calculations work?", 
    StudentMinAchieved = 
     Dynamic[(StudentAPts[[1]]/SchoolAPts[[1]] > 
         mark4) && (StudentAPts[[2]]/SchoolAPts[[2]] > mark4)]}
   }]
 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Use something like

   ```
   SetAttributes[restrictedInputField, HoldFirst];
   restrictedInputField[expr_] := 
      InputField[Dynamic[expr, (If[0 <= # < 10, expr = #] &)], Number, FieldSize -> 1];
   ```

   and *do not* use `ContinuousAction -> True` (if there is a way to make it work with it, I don't know it). Your code will then look like:

   ```
   numTable[x_, y_ /; EvenQ[y]] := 
      restrictedInputField[initPtsPartA[[x, y]]];
   ```

   and you can make `restrictedInputField` also local to your `DynamicModule`. The price to pay is that the input gets updated only after either `Enter` is perssed (after the number is typed in), or the focus leaves the input field. To my mind, this is acceptable, but of course you may have different opinion.
2. *Do not* use `Dynamic` in

   ```
   initPtsPartSum[x_, y_, col_] := Dynamic@Total[initPtsPartA[[x ;; y, col]]];
   ```

   instead, use simply:

   ```
   initPtsPartSum[x_, y_, col_] := Total[initPtsPartA[[x ;; y, col]]];
   ```

   By wrapping `Dynamic` around it, you prevent any arithmetic with it, since the `Dynamic` wrapper stays wrapped around your expression in all arithmetic etc operations you perform later.

Comment: What is the issue with `ContinuousAction->True` Leonid?

Comment: @Rojo I don't know, it just didn't work for me. When enabled in my version of the code, it prevented me from changing the original value in an input field. I did not look very hard at it though, perhaps I overlooked something obvious.

Comment: Oh, well, you can't delete because when you delete the value it becomes `Null` (which is allowed even when you only allow `Number`) and `Null` isn't 0 <= # < 10 &. But allowing for `Null` fixes it in my machine. Also, you could select the digit before typing the new one so you don't go through `Null`

Comment: @Rojo Good point, thanks. I will edit the post some time soon to incorporate this.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin
I think I  got the solution to the InputField problem.
Please try 
InputField[Dynamic[x, If[0 <= # <= 12, x = #, Null] &], Number,  ContinuousAction -> True, FieldSize -> 2]
and in an extra input cell
Dynamic@x

Use always tab to edit the input field.

Entering 22 makes Dynamic x to 2, a value which does not destroy some lines down in my code.

Comment: @ReinhardSimonovits Your code does not work for me, but the following modification (which implements the suggestion on Rojo) does:`InputField[
 Dynamic[x, If[# === Null || 0 <= # <= 12, x = #] &], Number,  ContinuousAction -> True, FieldSize -> 2]`.